# Qt - rootIndex gets reset each time QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidateFilter is called

Tags: python, qt, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyside

I need a `QTabWidget` where each tab contains a `QTreeView`. And each `QTreeView` shows
one "branch" of a larger model. The user has a `QLineEdit` which live-filters
the view based on whatever they type. I have a reproduction of the GUI + issue below.

The problem is that I use `QTreeView::setRootIndex` in order to display a single,
inner branch of the main model. The `QLineEdit` "filterer" is implemented with a
`QSortFilterProxyModel`. Whenever the user types, I call
`QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidateFilter` to get re-filter from scratch. These two
methods, `QTreeView::setRootIndex` and `QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidateFilter`, do not
mix well together.

When `QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidateFilter` is called, the index that I had
previously set using `QTreeView::setRootIndex` is now invalid. The `QTreeView` then
shows the whole tree, instead of the "branch" that I had previously selected using `setRootIndex`. The `QTreeView` effectively "forgets" the root index I had set.

I have a reproduction of the issue below

```py
import functools

from Qt import QtCore, QtWidgets

_NO_ROW = -1
_NUMBER_OF_BRANCHES = 3


class _MatchProxy(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    """Use a callable function to determine if an index should be hidden from view or not."""

    def __init__(self, matcher, parent=None):
        super(_MatchProxy, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self._matcher = matcher

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_index):
        return self._matcher(source_index)


class _MultiTree(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """A widget which makes smaller, individual QTreeViews for each section of an given index."""

    def __init__(self, source_index, parent=None):
        super(_MultiTree, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())

        model = source_index.model()

        self._views = []

        for index in range(model.rowCount(source_index)):
            section = model.index(index, 0, parent=source_index)
            label = model.data(section, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
            view.setModel(model)
            view.setRootIndex(section)

            self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(label))
            self.layout().addWidget(view)

            self._views.append(view)

    def iter_models(self):
        for view in self._views:
            yield view.model()

    def iter_views(self):
        for view in self._views:
            yield view


class Node(object):
    """A generic name + children + parent graph node class."""

    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(Node, self).__init__()

        self._name = name
        self._children = []
        self._parent = parent

        if self._parent:
            self._parent.add_child(self)

    def add_child(self, node):
        node._parent = self
        self._children.append(node)

    def get_child(self, row):
        return self._children[row]

    def get_children(self):
        return list(self._children)

    def get_label(self):
        return self._name

    def get_parent(self):
        return self._parent

    def get_row(self):
        parent = self.get_parent()

        if not parent:
            return _NO_ROW

        return parent.get_children().index(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{self.__class__.__name__}({self._name!r}, parent={self._parent!r})".format(
            self=self
        )


class Branch(Node):
    """Syntax sugar for debugging. This class isn't "necessary" for the reproduction."""

    pass


class Model(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    """The basic Qt model which contains the entire tree, including each branch."""

    def __init__(self, roots, parent=None):
        super(Model, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self._roots = roots

    def _get_node(self, index):
        return index.internalPointer()

    def columnCount(self, _):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None

        node = self._get_node(index)

        return node.get_label()

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if not parent.isValid():
            return self.createIndex(row, 0, self._roots[row])

        parent_node = self._get_node(parent)
        child_node = parent_node.get_child(row)

        return self.createIndex(row, column, child_node)

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        node = self._get_node(index)
        parent = node.get_parent()

        if not parent:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(node.get_row(), 0, parent)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return len(self._roots)

        node = self._get_node(index)

        return len(node.get_children())


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """The main widget / window which has the filterer + QTreeViews."""

    def __init__(self, model, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())

        self._filterer = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self._tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()

        self._set_model(model)

        self.layout().addWidget(self._filterer)
        self.layout().addWidget(self._tabs)

        self._filterer.textChanged.connect(self._update_current_view)

    def _replace_model_with_filterer_proxy(self, view):
        def _match(line_edit, index):
            if not index.isValid():
                return True  # Show everything, don't filter anything

            current = line_edit.text().strip()

            if not current:
                return True  # Show everything, don't filter anything.

            return current in index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)

        model = view.model()
        current_root = view.rootIndex()
        proxy = _MatchProxy(functools.partial(_match, self._filterer))
        proxy.setSourceModel(model)
        proxy.setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(True)
        view.setModel(proxy)
        view.setRootIndex(proxy.mapFromSource(current_root))

    def _set_model(self, model):
        tabs_count = model.rowCount(QtCore.QModelIndex())

        for row in range(tabs_count):
            branch_index = model.index(row, 0)
            tab_name = model.data(branch_index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            widget = _MultiTree(branch_index)

            for view in widget.iter_views():
                self._replace_model_with_filterer_proxy(view)

            self._tabs.addTab(widget, tab_name)

    def _update_current_view(self):
        widget = self._tabs.currentWidget()

        for proxy in widget.iter_models():
            proxy.invalidateFilter()


def _make_branch_graph():
    default = Node("default")
    optional = Node("optional")

    Node("camera", parent=default)
    Node("set", parent=default)
    light = Node("light", parent=default)
    Node("directional light", parent=light)
    spot = Node("spot light", parent=light)
    Node("light center", parent=spot)
    Node("volume light", parent=light)

    Node("model", parent=optional)
    surfacing = Node("surfacing", parent=optional)
    Node("look", parent=surfacing)
    Node("hair", parent=surfacing)
    Node("fur", parent=surfacing)
    Node("rig", parent=optional)

    return (default, optional)


def _make_full_graph():
    roots = []

    for index in range(_NUMBER_OF_BRANCHES):
        branch = Branch("branch_{index}".format(index=index))

        for node in _make_branch_graph():
            branch.add_child(node)

        roots.append(branch)

    return roots


def main():
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    roots = _make_full_graph()
    model = Model(roots)
    window = Widget(model)
    window.show()

    application.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- Run the code above to open the GUI. The tabs + inner QTreeViews should look like this:

```
QTabWidget tab - branch_0
    QTreeView (default)
        - camera
        - set
        - light
            - directional light
            - spot light
                - light center
            - volume light
    QTreeView (optional)
        - model
        - surfacing
            - look
            - hair
            - fur
        - rig
QTabWidget tab - branch_1
    - Same as branch_0
QTabWidget tab - branch_2
    - Same as branch_0
```

That is the correct, expected node display. Now in the filterer QLineEdit, type
in "light". You'll now get:

```
QTabWidget tab - branch_0
    QTreeView (default)
        - light
            - directional light
            - spot light
                - light center
            - volume light
    QTreeView (optional)
        - branch_0
            - default
                - light
                    - directional light
                    - spot light
                        - light center
                    - volume light
        - branch_1
            - default
                - light
                    - directional light
                    - spot light
                        - light center
                    - volume light
        - branch_2
            - default
                - light
                    - directional light
                    - spot light
                        - light center
                    - volume light
QTabWidget tab - branch_1
    - Same as branch_0
QTabWidget tab - branch_2
    - Same as branch_0
```

Here you can see that the QTreeView labelled "optional" now displays the
contents of every branch, not just the one branch like it was supposed to.

This is not the intended behavior. For reference, this is the view which I was
hoping to get:

```
QTabWidget tab - branch_0
    QTreeView (default)
        - default
            - light
                - directional light
                - spot light
                    - light center
                - volume light
    QTreeView (optional) [EMPTY, no children]
QTabWidget tab - branch_1
    - Same as branch_0
QTabWidget tab - branch_2
    - Same as branch_0
```

Also notice that if you clear the filterer QLineEdit's text, "", you don't go
back to the first graph. The "optional" QTreeView is stuck being shown
everything, in every QTreeView.

Now in the filterer QLineEdit text, type "asdf". Now the graph is

```
QTabWidget tab - branch_0
    QTreeView (default)
        - branch_0
        - branch_1
        - branch_2
    QTreeView (optional)
        - branch_0
        - branch_1
        - branch_2
QTabWidget tab - branch_1
    - Same as branch_0
QTabWidget tab - branch_2
    - Same as branch_0
```

When my intended view was

```
QTabWidget tab - branch_0
    QTreeView (default) [EMPTY]
    QTreeView (optional) [EMPTY]
QTabWidget tab - branch_1
    - Same as branch_0
QTabWidget tab - branch_2
    - Same as branch_0
```

And if you clear the filterer text with "", now both QTreeViews show everything across all branches.

Is there a simple way to get the intended graph that I'm describing? Maybe
there's a way to re-run QSortFilterProxyModel without invalidating indices, or
some other mechanism I can use to get the same effect? At the moment I'm
getting around the problem by "saving and restoring" the rootIndex for each
view, pre and post invalidateFilter. But my approach for that doesn't work in
all cases and feels like a hack.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't edit a question to provide an answer, as it makes the post confusing. If you're not sure if the proposed answer works, wait until you can test it and *then* accept it. If you have a *different* solution, then create an answer with that, but don't do it if you just want to show how the existing answer is implemented in your code.

Comment: I had to edit it since I tested your code and it didn't quite work. That said, I wanted to give you the accepted answer since you must've worked hard on that answer. But if you'd prefer I do a separate response then ofc I'll do that for you.

FWIW I've seen other people provide solutions in their question, it's not that confusing. Those granted in those cases their code was much shorter.

Comment: The fact that you could see answers in the question only means that nobody took care of notifying it or rolling back. The question field is for questions, answers must be in the answer section, that's not my preference, it's how the website is supposed to be used. That said, if something doesn't work in an answer, use comments to specify *what* doesn't work: an answer is not final, and might also be wrong; notifying the author about that is useful to you, to the author (who might learn something new or realize their mistakes), and to other readers.

Comment: Also, assuming that your answer is more correct, you should at least explain *why*. Posting the full code without any explanation seems just useful to you, but in this way you're forcing everybody else to compare the original code and the new one, find the differences and try to understand *why* they were made. Sorry, but right now your answer doesn't seem to add anything useful to justify a *different* answer since the modification seems to be caused by a problem in your original question and is not really related to the actual problem (the validity of the root index).

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that when applying filtering, unaccepted indexes become invalid indexes, and for Qt an invalid index is the same as the *root* index.
Since you're setting the root index of the view to an index that the filter makes invalid, the result the same as doing `setRootIndex(QModelIndex())`, which shows the whole model.

In fact, the same problem you see in the "optional" view can be also experienced if you try to filter the model using a string that doesn't match *any* of the "default" branch items: it will show the whole root tree model, and that's because your `_match` function returns `True` if the index is invalid, so the root will be shown anyway (in normal situations, it would show an empty model).
Note on this aspect: I'm not sure about the desired behavior, but if the filter doesn't match anything, it shouldn't return `True`, as that will make valid all root indexes, which in your case will show the root even if it wasn't supposed to be the shown index.

The source of the problem comes from the fact that the model doesn't know about the root index of the view (nor it should!) and the view cannot know *when* an invalid root index becomes valid again (and, again, nor it should). See [this discussion on a similar matter](https://forum.qt.io/topic/104345/qfilesystemmodel-and-qsortfilterproxymodel-root-index-is-not-preserved).

A possible solution (which doesn't solve the question of the *accepted* invalid root), is to keep track of the root index and then update the view by connecting to `rowsRemoved` and, most importantly, `rowsInserted` signals of the model so that we can restore the original root index whenever it becomes "available" again:

```
class TreePersistentRootIndex(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    _sourceRootIndex = QtCore.QModelIndex()
    def setModel(self, model):
        if self.model() and isinstance(self.model(), QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
            self.model().layoutChanged.disconnect(self.checkRootIndex)
            self.model().rowsRemoved.disconnect(self.checkRootIndex)
            self.model().rowsInserted.disconnect(self.checkRootIndex)
        super().setModel(model)
        self._model = model
        if isinstance(model, QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
            model.layoutChanged.connect(self.checkRootIndex)
            model.rowsRemoved.connect(self.checkRootIndex)
            model.rowsInserted.connect(self.checkRootIndex)

    def checkRootIndex(self):
        if (not self._sourceRootIndex.isValid() or 
            not isinstance(self.model(), QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel)):
                return
        rootIndex = self.model().mapFromSource(self._sourceRootIndex)
        if rootIndex != self.rootIndex():
            super().setRootIndex(rootIndex)

    def setRootIndex(self, rootIndex):
        super().setRootIndex(rootIndex)
        if isinstance(self.model(), QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
            rootIndex = self.model().mapToSource(rootIndex)
        self._sourceRootIndex = rootIndex


class _MultiTree(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, source_index, parent=None):
        # ...
        for index in range(model.rowCount(source_index)):
            section = model.index(index, 0, parent=source_index)
            label = model.data(section, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            view = TreePersistentRootIndex()
            # ...
```

To overcome the problem of the accepted root index, you might consider changing the filtering behavior, or eventually (if you're *completely* sure that if the filter doesn't match any child item it shouldn't show anything in child-root indexes), use `setRowHidden()` using `True` (as in *hide*) if the resulting index is invalid or `False` (as in *show*) otherwise.

A possible implementation (not fully tested) might be the following:

```
    def checkRootIndex(self):
        # ...as above, then:
        if rootIndex.isValid() != self._sourceRootIndex.isValid():
            hide = not rootIndex.isValid()
            for row in range(self.model().rowCount(rootIndex)):
                self.setRowHidden(row, rootIndex.parent(), hide)
```

Comment: It's perfect, thank you very much for your help!! I'll post my full, working example, using your code and accept yours

Comment: I've been working with this solution for a few weeks and noticed a couple issues that I had to fix. The first is, if I use (model) beginMoveRows(), the tree view will segmentation fault. I fixed the problem by changing `self._sourceRootIndex = rootIndex`
 to `self._sourceRootIndex = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(rootIndex)`. The second issue is beginRemoveRows() also segmentation faults. To fix it, I had to add a rather strange solution. This comment section is too small so I'll post it as a separate answer. Could you please loot at it and give your thoughts on why it works?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out @musicamante answer and hit some issues. If I remove rows or move rows, Qt would segmentation fault. I'll address both points and their solutions as separate sections below.

### Moving Rows

Moving a common ancestor of a root index causes Qt to segmentation fault. To fix it, I had to change `setRootIndex` to store a persisent index.

```
-         self._sourceRootIndex = rootIndex
+         self._sourceRootIndex = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(rootIndex)
```

### Removing Rows

This one was trickier. I found a solution but I don't actually know **why** it works.

During `_TreePersistentRootIndex.checkRootIndex`, `setRootIndex` is called if the found `rootIndex` doesn't match `self.rootIndex()`. If you delete a row in the model and `_TreePersistentRootIndex.checkRootIndex` is called, the GUI segmentation faults. To fix it, I added this:

```
        if rootIndex != self.rootIndex():
+           rootIndex = rootIndex.model().index(
+               rootIndex.row(),
+               rootIndex.column(),
+               rootIndex.parent(),
+           )
            self.setRootIndex(rootIndex)
```

And for some reason, re-acquiring the root index explicitly prevents the segmentation fault.

[Here is a reproduction of the segmentation fault](https://pastebin.com/8tTWZ2eY) (If you load that reproduction as is, it will work as expected. But if you comment out the line mentioned above, it will segmentation fault whenever the "Delete the branch" button is pressed)